# Eclipse behaves strangely on Ubuntu 9.10. My buttons won't work after the upgrade!

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, ubuntu, button

Everything was fine until I did an upgrade from Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10. Since then, Eclipse just doesn't respond properly. The following are the symptoms I can see:

- When I click on update, it grabs the
  available updates but doesn't show
  them. Any internal window that is
  displayed has corrupted buttons
- I cannot click on any of the buttons. I
  have to keep pressing Tab to
  highlight that specific button and
  then hit spacebar.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some issues with the GTK on Ubuntu 9.10. This happens when you download eclipse from the main site rather than the ubuntu archives. The following fix was mentioned from the bug fix archives of Ubuntu (at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/442078):

Start eclipse with the following:

```
GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 /pathto/eclipse
```

I've had a lot of problems with it, so hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Please see also
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=291257

Answer (score 0):

Good fix, I made a script to run eclipse

```
#!/bin/sh
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1
/opt/eclipse-3.5/eclipse #you should change this line width your ECLIPSE_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution for launcher for eclipse (and eclipse-based soft like aptana studio)

1) Create a script in a folder with eclipse executable

```
#!/bin/bash
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true

#launch eclipse from current dir
`dirname $0`/eclipse
```

2) Create a launcher on desktop or panel

This solution fits best if you have multiple eclipse instances or sometimes relocate your app folders.

Answer (score 0):

I updated eclipse using Help->Check for updates menu in eclipse.
Then it worked.